# Working search box for API call

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong in my code. I'm trying to get the gif image to appear after entering something into the search input box and clicking the search button.

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
document.body.appendChild(button);
button.innerHTML = "Search"

var input = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(input);

function afterLoad() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
    var image = document.createElement('img')
    image.src = data.data[0].images.original.url
    document.body.appendChild(image)
    }

function afterClick() {
    var terms = target.value.split(' ').join('+')
    alert(terms);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.addEventListener('load', afterLoad)
    request.open('GET', 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q='+terms+'&limit=1&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC')
    request.send()

    }

button.addEventListener("click", afterClick)
```

Comment: Is the point to just show the image? Instead of XHR, what about creating an `img` element, setting the `src` directly using the URL you are building in that function, and then `appendChild()` that to the page?

Comment: Yes the point is to just show the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var button = document.createElement('button');
document.body.appendChild(button);
button.innerHTML = "Search";

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.id = "search"; // *** set id ***
document.body.appendChild(input);

function afterLoad() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    console.log(data);
    image.src = data.data[0].images.original.url;
    document.body.appendChild(image);
    }

function afterClick() {
    // changed target to focus search
    var terms = document.getElementById("search").value.split(' ').join('+');
    alert(terms);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener('load', afterLoad);
    request.open('GET', 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q='+terms+'&limit=1&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC');
    request.send();

    }

button.addEventListener("click", afterClick);
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Did not found out where you define target. Gave the input a id and took it value. Working fine.

**Edit:**
Image appears if i search for "xxxxx"